# Java code to translate using a particular language dictionary

Tags: java, python, dictionary

I am not that good at java program, i am trying to do something like this please help.

I want to make a simple translator for one particular language, say **korean**.

Can i download a korean - english dictionary from internet and use it as a hash map or a dictionary datastructure to search for korean word based on the english input i give?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/), its very easy to implement. For sure you will need an internet connection for it to work.

```
Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
String text = translate.translate("Good morning", Language.ENGLISH, Language.KOREAN)
```

Comment: Hey thnx, but i dont want to use google api becuase i want a program to convert words to mainly korean without using internet. So i thought if there is any such english-korean dictionary i can make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a map is one possible & easy way (as shown in the short example). Though you still would need to do a big effort for problems like upper/lower case of words, punctuation, verbs etc.

```
    Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dictionary.put("this", "das");
    dictionary.put("is", "ist");
    dictionary.put("my", "mein");
    dictionary.put("house", "haus");

    String translate = "this is my new house";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(translate, " ");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String key = st.nextToken();
        String translatedWord = dictionary.get(key);
        if (translatedWord != null) {
            result.append(translatedWord);
        } else {
            result.append("*" + key + "*"); // Unknown word
        }
        result.append(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());
```